# Is there a way to have a React child component displayed as a string, with indentations, returns, and with jsx syntactic sugar?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm not sure if I'm explaining what I want right. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ExampleChild extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello!!</p>
    );
  }
}

class ExampleParent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ExampleChild />
        Here's the ExampleChild code:
        {ExampleChild.toString()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ExampleParent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

An get the following output to the DOM, with all the correct indentations and spaces of the actual code:

Hello!!
Here's the ExampleChild code:

> render() {
>    return (
>       < p >Hello!!< /p >
>    ); 
>   }

If the child component is just a stateless, functional component, I can do a .toString(), but it returns it in pure Javascript. It doesn't return it in the JSX format, or with the original returns, and indentations. I would also like to be able to do this with React class components as well. Is there maybe a library that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the react syntax highlighting library [react-syntax-highlighter](https://github.com/conorhastings/react-syntax-highlighter)

I created an npm [script](https://github.com/ryanpaixao/ryanpaixao.com-source/blob/master/scripts/rawcode.sh) to make copies of my react components and exported them as [template literals](https://github.com/ryanpaixao/ryanpaixao.com-source/tree/master/src/components/pages/rawFiles). Which, then would be displayed via react-syntax-highlighter.

Working example: [ryanpaixao.com](https://ryanpaixao.com)

I didn't go with raw-loader because I didn't want to eject my create-react-app. (I would've had to in order to configure webpack) Also, it seems that I would've had to set all .js files to be imported as strings (maybe there's a way around that).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `renderToStaticMarkup` from `react-dom/server`, but only for the resulting HTML markup.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";
import Hello from "./Hello";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Component:</p>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <p>As HTML:</p>
    <pre>{renderToStaticMarkup(<Hello name="CodeSandbox" />)}</pre>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Check it out on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lyzj1xxyxm).

If you want the whole JSX file, you could import with something like [`raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) and print it inside `pre`s as well.